# How to make one loop with PathModifier()?

Tags: android, andengine

AndEngine. I use Path() and PathModifier() for my game.

```
path = new Path(2).to(10, 10).to(100, 100);
sprite.registerEntityModifier(new LoopEntityModifier(new PathModifier(1f, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {


            public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {                  
            }


            public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {                   
            }


            public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {
            }


            public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {               

            }
    }, EaseSineInOut.getInstance())));
```

It works, but I dont't want endless loop for it. Then I changed method onPathFinished( ):

```
public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {               
                pEntity.clearEntityModifiers();
            }
```

But after that my sprite have done 1 loop and return in first position (10,10) and stopped.
So, how to make a stop in position (100,100) after 1 loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `yourSprite.setPosition(100,100)` in `onPathFinished()`

Comment: Thanks. But I've found solution. Need to use PathModifier class instead LoopEntityModifier.

Comment: Thanks Anivaler with the use of PathModifier class instead of LoopEntityModifier we can resolve this issue.